# Urn with marbles

Tags: probability

This is a simple one:
An urn contains 3 red and 3 green marbles and a second one contains 2 red and 1 green. If we pick one marble from each urn, what is the probability we get one of each color?

Probability of picking 1 red from first urn and 1 green from second: 3/6*1/3=1/6
Probability of picking 1 green from first urn and 1 red from second: 3/6*2/3=2/6
Total probability = 1/6+2/6=3/6.
Is this correct? Can we apply Bayes theorem in this case?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can get either R from Urn 1 and G from Urn 2

or G from Urn 1 and R from Urn 2

Thus the required probability $= \frac{3}{6} \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{3}{6} \frac{2}{3} =  \frac{1}{2}$

There is no need to apply bayes' theorem for this problem

Answer (score 2):

To make things more simple start by picking a marble from the second urn. It will have color red or green. In both cases the probability that a marble picked from the first urn also has that color is $\frac12$.

To spare this simplicity keep Bayes (and others) out.